# G++ generate logically wrong assembly code

Tags: c++, g++, real-mode

Today I am using g++ to compile a c++ file, but there seems a problem with g++ that when a variable of char type comparing with any number of char type with bit 7 set to 1, g++ will always assume that is false thus makes the stuff wrong.More specifically,the c++ code looks like this:

```
  // test.cpp
    __asm__(".code16gcc \n\t");
    int equals0(char i)
    {
        return i==0x80;
    }
    int equals1(char i)
    {
        return i==0x10;
    }
    int equals2(int i)
    {
        return i==0x80;
    }
```

Note that there is a preamble sentence ".code16gcc",which I used to generate real mode codes.

To be more concrete, my g++ version is "g++ (GCC) 6.4.0" on cygwin.

Now, compile this file into assembly code using:
`g++ -S -o test.s test.cpp -m32`

And the resulting file is:

```
     // some trival information is omitted
    .code16gcc 

    .text
    ...
__Z7equals0c://func equals0
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $4, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movb    %al, -4(%ebp)  //no comparison with 0x80 
    movl    $0, %eax   //always returns 0
    leave
    ret
    ...
__Z7equals1c://func equals1
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $4, %esp
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax
    movb    %al, -4(%ebp)
    cmpb    $16, -4(%ebp)  // a comparison with 0x10
    sete    %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax    // returns value depend on the result of comparison
    leave
    ret
    ...
__Z7equals2i://func equals2
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    cmpl    $128, 8(%ebp) //also a comparison
    sete    %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Note that function equals0 will always return 0(saved in eax), but function equals1 will return the correct result, based on the generated assembly file.

And also note that the only difference between function equals0  and equals1 is the constant used to compare with,0x80 for equals0 and 0x10 for equals1.Based on this, we can say g++ has generated logically wrong code.

Anybody knows why and will explain this?

Comment: You really should trust your GCC compiler. It has been extensively tested. Question first your own code.

Comment: (signed) `char` is promote to `int`, and char (`[-128;127[`)cannot be equal to 128.

Comment: Is `[low;high[` a specific notation? I nearly edited your answer to `[low;high]`, but I see you did it here too.

Comment: Try with the g++ `-funsigned-char` compiler switch.

Comment: @Useless: I wanted to write `[-128;128[` first (close-open interval); then fall back to `[-128;127]` forgetting to change open to close.

Comment: Alternatively, `return (i&0xFF)==0x80;`

Comment: @Eljay why? Suppose i is of type int, it is needless to truncate i to lower 8-bit because I want the whole integer to be equal 0x80;  and suppose i is of type char, it is forever true that (i&0xFF)==i .

Comment: @DouglasFultonShaw the bitwise operations ignore signed / unsigned states of the variable; while your tests do not.

Answer (score 8):

`0x80` (`int` `128`) is out of range of signed char (`[-128;127]`).

so a signed char cannot be equal to `0x80`

Comment: So without considering the fact that 0x80 is outside the range of signed char,what if some person writes this :
 char arr[1];  
  arr[0]=0x80;
if(arr[0]==0x80)
  /*some code*/
And it surprises him that  /* some code*/ is not executed, isn't this logically wrong?

Comment: Yes, the person writing the code made a logical error. What if they tried to store the value `1e12` in a `char` - should the compiler also somehow magically squeeze that into 8 bits?

Comment: BTW, if you want to do bit-twiddling, use unsigned types (eg, `uint8_t` for raw bytes).

Comment: I do this because the language makes me possible to do it. I am just assigning a number with length of 8-bit to length of a 8-bit type,there is no error.And when I compare the two 8-bit numbers, bit-wise comparison should be taken as the way.

Comment: @Douglas Fulton Shaw that's simply not how C++ works.

Comment: I would have warning for given code: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79ed16d7c33ea6ce). So, mistake should be easy to fix in that case.

Comment: @Jarod42 Exactly! The compiler gives an understandable message.Besides, changing the type of arr to 'unsigned char' and if not redundant adding an 'u' suffix to 0x80(e.g. 0x80u) will fix all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

> Note that there is a preamble sentence ".code16gcc", which I used to generate real mode codes.

Wrong. Your `__asm__(".code16gcc \n\t");` is just *emitting* some assembler directive (which would make your *assembler* to switch mode). But you want to change the *behavior* of your GCC compiler (e.g. you expect GCC to emit real mode 16 bit assembler code).

AFAIK, you cannot do that easily. Perhaps you could find a variant of GCC (perhaps some cross-compiler) to emit real mode code, and then you need to use that variant on  your C++ translation  unit. You are dreaming of some `-m16realmode` flag for GCC which does not exist. And GCC [`-m16` mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options) (very confusingly named!) still emits 32 bits code:

> The `-m16` option is the same as `-m32`, except for that it outputs the `.code16gcc` assembly directive at the beginning of the assembly output so that the binary can run in 16-bit mode.

<sup>(actually, the binary *cannot* run  in 16-bit mode unless you *provide* and call some *extra* code switching to 32 bits; you probably need to write that switching-mode code in assembler)</sup>

In 2017, there is no reason to use legacy real mode 16 bits code. The only case where that might be useful is when you code a boot loader. Then you should not use GCC, and more importantly you should use some *existing* boot loader (like [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)) and focus your efforts on the rest.

If you are coding a toy operating system (and you should code it at least in 32 bits mode), look on [OSDEV wiki](http://osdev.org/) for hints.

> Now, compile this file into assembly code using: `g++ -S -o test.s test.cpp -m32`

That still use 32 bits mode (not 16 bit legacy) for the entire source (and erroneously inserts a *wrong* `.code16gcc` assembler directive inside it). BTW, you'll better ask for some optimizations. So I recommend compiling with `g++ -m32 -Wall -O -fverbose-asm -S -o test.s test.cpp`.

BTW, you are confused by the signness of  `char` which is *fixed* within the `-m32` x86 architecture (so `char` is a `signed char` on x86; on  PowerPC it might be an `unsigned char`). I don't recommend recompiling with `-funsigned-char`  but if you do that you are changing your [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and you need to recompile *everything*, including your C standard library and your C++ standard library.

Comment: '-m16', it does exists. Invoke the info command with : info '(gcc)x86 Options', take a look at the -m32,-m16 specifiction page, it says:
     The '-m16' option is the same as '-m32', except for that it outputs
     the '.code16gcc' assembly directive at the beginning of the
     assembly output so that the binary can run in 16-bit mode.